# Golang - Issues go get-ting basic commands "vet" and "godoc"

Tags: macos, go, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I've just installed Homebrew Go 1.2.2 on OSX Mavericks. Everything seems to be running fine, except that when I try either of the following commands:

```
$ go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc
$ go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/vet
```

I get this stack trace:

```
/Users/sozorogami/go/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/exact/exact.go:255: new(big.Rat).SetFrac(x.val, int1).Float32 undefined (type *big.Rat has no field or method Float32)
/Users/sozorogami/go/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/exact/exact.go:255: not enough arguments to return
/Users/sozorogami/go/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/exact/exact.go:257: x.val.Float32 undefined (type *big.Rat has no field or method Float32)
/Users/sozorogami/go/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/exact/exact.go:257: not enough arguments to return
```

`go get`s to other repos seem to work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use homebrew. Use the standard pkg installer, I found it gave me much less headaches, especially with installing go.tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a big fail from their part, but if you look at the repo, you can see there are a branch for 1.3 and a branch for 1.2.

You can fix it by doing this:

```
cd ~/go/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/exact
hg up release-branch.go1.2
go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc
```

Note that if you try to update (go get -u), the repo will go back to the 'default' branch and it will fail again. Simply update to the correct branch after the update.

Comment: Or simply use go 1.3rc1 which is faster and better than 1.2.x anyway.

Comment: I tried with 1.3beta2 and it was failing :p. Good to know it works with rc1

Comment: I stand corrected, using today's tip I had to do what you said except I had to use `hg up release-branch.go1.3`, tip is broken for both.